# Connect a 3G Android phone with a WiFi-only tab to see phone call information on the latter

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, connection-issues, 3g

I own a WiFi-only Android tab and an Android phone with 3G.

I use the tab regularly at work or while working out on the treadmill, and often I miss a phone call on my Android phone while using the tab.

Is there any App or other possibility to link the phone to the tab to be able to see incoming phone calls on the WiFi tab? Via Bluetooth, for example?

(I also own a Sony smartwatch which does exactly this, but I'm looking for a solution on my tab).

Comment: If you are willing to pay there is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apdroid.tabtalk&hl=en_GBTablet Talk that allows you to route SMS through your tablet. I can't find a voice option for this though. I'll keep looking. You may have to use Google Voice or something VoIP like Skype.

Comment: I certainly am willing to pay if the software works. Maybe I should emphasize that seeing the incoming phone call information would satisfy me already, no need to be able to answer the call on my tablet (thus no VoIP routing required).

Answer (score 0):

[MightyText](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.texty.sms) is a free app that allows you to get communication notifications on your tablet through WiFi. While its geared for people that would want to text from their tablet, it also has some other really nice features. Among them are call notifications, battery alerts, and photo syncing. They also have a Chrome extension which allows you to get the same features on a computer. I used to use this app all the time and highly recommend it.